# How to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

The archive "http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
zesty-security Release" does not have a release file
What do I do then ?

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1359504/edit) to include the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

A system upgrade only proceeds from a fully updated system. Update your system first:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then run the `do-release-upgrade` command.

Comment: @nobody Indeed, that will be better. I updated the question. Thanks!